# Internal error -12 at the server when calling an API with the method SEND in Uniface 10

Tags: certificate, uniface

I have a Uniface 10 service which makes an HTTP request to an API interface. The URL is a connection secured with HTTPS, such as "https://www.example.com/api/weather".

I execute the HTTP request as follows to get data from the API:

`vStatus = vUHTTP->SEND(vURI, "POST", vUser, vPassword, vHeaders, vContent, vResponse)`

As a result, I am getting the value -12 in the variable "vStatus" today.

The manual of Uniface 10 says that the value -12 in the method SEND stands for the following:

```
An internal error occurred. If the request is an HTTPS request, the certification may be incorrectly configured. As an alternative, use the SET_FLAGS.
```

See: [Uniface Reference - SEND](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/Uniface/10/uniface/_reference/componentAPIs/httpExecutionOperations/SEND.htm)

I understand that an internal error occurred at the calling API.

What I do not understand:

- I don't understand why from one day to the next the certificate is configured incorrectly.
- I don't understand why I should now adjust the SET_FLAGS method.

So now I ask myself how to solve the problem.